# Maven Deploy ignore already uploaded artifacts

Tags: java, maven

I am using the maven deploy command to upload generated artifacts to jfrog artifactory. This command works well, but in sometimes the Jfrog returns to me an error 500 Internal server error for any reason.

My project have many modules and sub-projects. This question is, how Can I retry the maven deploy just for artifacts that with errors in upload or artifacts that were not uploaded yet. When I tried the command again the Jfrog returns to me an error 403 forbiden because this one artifact was already uploaded.

There is any way to ignore the already uploaded articfacts in Maven?

Comment: Are you reuploading snapshots or releases?

Comment: First I've got the impression you have a multi module with different versions instead of a single one for the whole multi module and furthermore you are deploying releases which is by default forbidden to redeploy which is correct. Apart from that 500 means there is really something wrong which you should investigate what is the real root cause of the problem...

Comment: Thanks for reply guys. @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I'm uploading with error just in release. The snapshots works fine because the jfrog accept a overwrite upload for snapshots.

Comment: @khmarbaise the reason for error 500 is upload overload. At some point in the day the jfrog starts to work a lot with many uploads and he just cann't stand it. My project despite having sub-modules, they all have the same version. I really wanted to just ignore the errors to retain the modules that have not yet been sent

Comment: Consider using nexus. The docker instance is trivially simple to get up and running

Comment: My client uses Jfrog, I can't change it.

Comment: Nexus or Jfrog have the same behaviour and won't work as well. I final solution was upload again the artefacts with the version increased.

Answer (score -2):

I didn't found a friendly way to solve that, then my final solution was to increase the artefact's versions and upload everything again.